# How to delete all the rows where each row's id is equal to another table's id (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

`mainGroup` (datasetID greater than or equal to 1788)

dataGroup' name is the bold text.

```
datasetID | dataGroup                   | dataDesc
----------+-----------------------------+----------
1790      | **dGroup1** note xxxx       | desc1
1789      | **dGroup1** late notice ..  | desc2
1788      | **dGroup1** jack ...        | desc3
```

ex) dGroup1

```
dGroup1_ID | create_date | datasetID
-----------+-------------+-------
379        | 01-01-01    | 1790
378        | 01-01-01    | 1789
377        | 01-01-01    | 1788
```

I want to remove the tows in dGroup1/dGroup2/dGroup3 table where its datasetID is equal to corresponding datasetID in the mainGroup table, where datasetID in the mainGroup is greater than equal to 1788.  (ex. 1790 for dGroup1, 1789 for dGroup2, etc.)

Instead of doing individually of deletion, is there any way to perform all at one?

Comment: Have you had a look at the [docmentation and its examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#d-using-joins-and-subqueries-to-data-in-one-table-to-delete-rows-in-another-table)? What about them weren't you sure on?

Comment: It looks like a simple where criteria with EXISTS but your question is not clear enough to write sample code. Sample what exactly you want to remove from which table?

Comment: It sounds like you have multiple tables you want to delete records from.  If that is the case, then you will have to use a separate DELETE for each table.

Comment: It is possible to do a multi table delete with partitioned views. But I would very much advise against them, and in any case will not work in this instance. You should normalize your tables so that all the groups are in one table

Answer (score 1):

So, you would like to delete records on tables `dGroup1`, `dGroup2` & `dGroup3` depending on the contents of table `mainGroup`.

For `dGroup1`, it looks like this:

```sql
DELETE t1
FROM dGroup1 t1
    INNER JOIN mainGroup t2
        ON t1.datasetID = t2.datasetID
        AND t2.datasetID >= 1788
```

You could repeat this for tables `dGroup2` and `dGroup3`.

Comment: facVV, was this helpful? If it was, please consider marking it as the correct answer. Thanks.